Web scraping using Rvest is not working as expected
I have been searching and reading number of rvest related articles on how to web scrape. Unfortunately, my attempts to learn various components involved has been unsuccessful. I understand some HTML syntax and am fluent in r but this is my first time working with rvest.
This is the source (inspect view). I'm trying to extract various pieces of information. I started with a test case on " title".

Here is my code so far...
x <- https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/browse?congress=118

read_html(x) %>% html_elements(xpath = "//*[@class = 'container']") %>% 
html_elements(xpath = ".//*[@class = 'searching row']") %>% 
html_elements(xpath = ".//*[@class = 'col-sm-8']")  %>% 
html_elements(xpath = ".//*[@class = 'results']") %>% 
html_text()

> "\n    "

As you can see, in the results class, I'm getting blank. What can I change to make this code work?
Thank you.

The authors of the website provide a scrapper for what you are looking for in this gitrepo

@JoshAllen: The gitrepo uses another source and the code uses another language. My remaining code uses govtrack and I am looking to continue using the same source.

The scrapper in the repo is used by the govtrack people to get the info for the website. The issue you are running into is that the website is using javascript to display its contents. read_html can't execute the javascript. If you only care about the info on one page use read_html_live. If you need to scrape the entire website you are probably going to need to use selenium to scroll the webpage see this answer for how to do it

@JoshAllen...I was just figuring out the selenium route and it's nice to get some confirmation that selenium could be the option. I'll look at the available resources and see how it pans out. Thanks.

from @joshallen The scrapper in the repo is used by the govtrack people to get the info for the website. The issue you are running into is that the website is using javascript to display its contents. read_html can't execute the javascript. If you only care about the info on one page use read_html_live. If you need to scrape the entire website you are probably going to need to use selenium to scroll the webpage see this answer for how to do it –
Josh Allen
Commented13 hours ago
